# Convert into separate date and time into one string with format moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using [moment js](https://momentjs.com/) and new in this. So right now I am getting separated time and date from html to javascript controller so I want to convert into one string with format in moment js.

```
console.log($scope.timeTo);
console.log($scope.dateTO);
```

Console OutPut:

```
04:00
23/05/2017
```

But I want to set time and date together  with momentjs.
Desired format:

```
2017-05-23T04:00:00
```

Comment: why not append it while printing it? will keep the things simple :)

Comment: @warcops. I want to do with moment js.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply concat your strings and then [parse](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) it with moment.

Then you can use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to get moment object in the format you need.

```js
var timeTo = '04:00';
var dateTo = '23/05/2017';
var m = moment(dateTo + timeTo, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
console.log(m.format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I want to remove +5:30 from format of time. can you suggest me?

Comment: @VSH I've updated my snippet, just pass `'YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss'` to [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)